# System.ArgumentException: 'Database names must be non-empty and not contain '.' or the null character. (Parameter 'databaseName')'

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Mongodb database with ASP.NET core for creating this API project and I ended up getting this error sorry it's an exception.Here I'm just using get method to retrieve all values from database. I have surfed the internet for the solution and it seems like no one got this kind of exception.

This is the interface for activity model:

```
    using Domain.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Domain.Repositories.Contracts
    {
        public interface IActivityRepository
        {
           
    
            List<Activity> Get();
            Activity Get(string id);
            Activity Create(Activity activity);
            void Update(string id);
            void Remove(string id);
            void Update(string id, Activity activity);
    
        }
    }
```

and it's implementation:

```
using Domain.Contexts;
using Domain.Models;
using Domain.Repositories.Contracts;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Domain.Repositories.Mongo
{
    public class ActivityRepository : IActivityRepository
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Activity> _activity;

        public ActivityRepository(IOneboardDtatabaseSettings settings, IMongoClient mongoclient)
        {
            var database = mongoclient.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _activity = database.GetCollection<Activity>(settings.ActivitesCollectionName);
        }
        Activity IActivityRepository.Create(Activity activity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public List<Activity> Get()
        {
            return _activity.Find(activity => true).ToList();
        }

        Activity IActivityRepository.Get(string id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IActivityRepository.Remove(string id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IActivityRepository.Update(string id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IActivityRepository.Update(string id, Activity activity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The exeception part lies here:

```
var database = mongoclient.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
```

program.cs :

```
using API.Config;
using Domain.Contexts;
using Domain.Repositories.Contracts;
using Domain.Repositories.Mongo;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Driver;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

/*****************************************
 *      SERVICES
 * **************************************/

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<OneboardDatabaseSettings>(
      builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OneboardDatabaseSettings)));


builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOneboardDtatabaseSettings>(sp =>
      sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<OneboardDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(s =>
     new MongoClient(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OneboardDatabase:ConnectionString")));


builder.Services.AddScoped<IActivityRepository, ActivityRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();





var app = builder.Build();

/*****************************************
 *      PIPELINE
 * **************************************/

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Global error handling registration
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And this is appsettings.json file and as per exception database and connection string looks fine to me

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:/Solustem/OneBoard/Logs/oneboard-provider-api-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Username} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CORS": {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "http://localhost:19006"
    ]
  },
  "JWT": {
    "ValidAudience": "User",
    "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:5144",
    "Key": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyYjZiOTVhOTMwMjFjMDJhODc5NDRhYSIsImlhdCI6MTY1NjE0NDYxNCwiZXhwIjozMzIxMzc0NDYxNH0.SC7JIawGhcleTEo7LpYptHqJ_xYmEQIuPWR8XF20FGQ",
    // This is to identify the hostel the user can manage
    "HostelID": "HostelID"
  },
  "Services": {
    "Strapi": {
      "BaseURL": "http://localhost:1337"
    },
    "Kaleyra": {
      "BaseURL": "https://api.kaleyra.io/v1/HXIN1705702387IN",
      "Key": "A673e59a98e51f4e6f766d67f603000b6"
    }
  },
  "OneboardDatabase": {
    "ActivitesCollectionName": "activities",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://Muralidharan:murali123@cluster0.fwttvjg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "DatabaseName": "myFirstDatabase"
  }
}
```

This is IOneboardDatabaseSettings

```
namespace Domain.Contexts
{
    public interface IOneboardDtatabaseSettings
    {
        
        
        string ActivitesCollectionName { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and it's implementation OneboardDatabaseSettings

```
namespace Domain.Contexts
{
    // This class acts as a template for configurations in appsettings file
    public class OneboardDatabaseSettings: IOneboardDtatabaseSettings
    {
        
        
        public string ActivitesCollectionName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have tried my best to find out why this exception throwing and I have no idea.

Comment: Can you show the part of Startup.cs (if you use .NET Core or  .NET 5) or Program.cs (if you use .NET 6) for the part how you read the configuration and set it to `IOneboardDtatabaseSettings`. And also may share the code for `IOneboardDtatabaseSettings`.

Comment: yup,I'll add it here.

Comment: Oh my.. I have named it as OneboardDatabase instead of OneboardDatabaseSettings in appsettings.json and you gave the spark for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<OneboardDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection('OneboardDatabase')
);
```